# Sinon Stub is not throwing an error when fs.readFileSynch also throws an error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

After going through all related issues regarding stubbing readFile/Sync with Sinon /Chai/ Mocha, the test is failing.

There's a basic getFile function that retrieves a file:

```
function getFile(path) {
const file = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8)
return file;
}

module.exports = {getFile}
```

and I want to create a test where getFile should throw an error if  fs.readFileSync also throws an error:

it('should throw an error if fs.readFileSync throws an error', () => {

I tried:

```
it('should throw an error if fs.readFileSync throws an error', () => {
  const error = new Error('some error message')
  const myStub = sinon.stub(fs, "readFileSync")
    myStub.throws(error)
  const filePath = "/Project/test.js" 
  const gFile = index.getFile(filePath)

  try {
    if(myStub.error === true) {
          gFile(error)       
  } catch (error) {
    expect(myStub).to.throw(error)
```

What I got was:

> 1 failing
> Error: some error message
> at Context.
> at process.processImmediate

Comment: Missing a quote after `"utf8`

Comment: Missing a closing brackets for `if(myStub.error === true) {` and `} catch (error) {`. Work on paying attention to your indentation, because it will avoid bugs and make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your error function in the Sinon throw method as below.

```
myStub.throws(new Error('some error message'));
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [chai expect docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) on `throw()`. There is this example:

```
var badFn = function () { throw new TypeError('Illegal salmon!'); };

expect(badFn).to.throw();
```

You see that `expect(badFn)` gets `badFn` not `badFn()`, so nowhere in the test is `badFn` actually *called*.

This means that `expect` calls `badFn`. And actually, `expect` needs to be the one to call it because it needs to catch the error.

So in your code, try this:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFileSync').throws();

const callGetFile = () => {
    index.getFile('some_file');
};

expect(callGetFile).to.throw();
```

Comment: The test is passing now, but does not print out the error message. I modified the gFile const to be a function and replaced the stub with the gFile const in the expect statement. I was on tutorials treadmill for a while, but they would usually explain the simplest of functions, such as sums and simple operations. I feel like there is a large gap to be filled.